# Using CSS to change span background color has no effect

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have applied `background-color: #C0C0C0;` to my span element `.grey_bg` but the background is not changing color. Why is that?

```css
    .grey_bg {

      width: 100%;

      background-color: #C0C0C0;

    }
```

```html
<span class="grey_bg">
        <h1>Hey</h1>
    </span>
```

Comment: Read the specs for `<span>` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) - *Permitted content: Phrasing content*, headings i.e. `<h1>` cannot be included, because it is not [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

Answer (score 9):

Because it's not really valid HTML to put block-level H1 element inside span (inline element). You can either use div instead of span

```css
.grey_bg {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey_bg"> 
    <h1>Hey</h1>
</div>
```

... or make span block-level too:

```css
span {display: block;}
.grey_bg {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<span class="grey_bg"> 
    <h1>Hey</h1>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

First your markup is not correct. You can't have a block element, `h3`, inside an inline element, `span`.

But in case you want to keep that markup, you have to make the container element to behave as `block`. So make it as:

```
.grey_bg { 
width: 100%; 
background-color: #C0C0C0; 
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect because your `span` is wrapping your `H` tag.

You should not use `span` to wrap `inline` element's like `H` tag's. Instead you want the span to be inside your `H` tag.

> The span element is the inline level generic container. It also helps to inform the structure of document, but it is used to group or wrap other inline elements and/or text, rather than block level elements.
>   The line between the two different types might seem fairly arbitrary at first. The difference to bear in mind is the type of content, and how it would appear when written down without any styling. A div is placed around a group of block level elements—for example, to wrap a heading plus a list of links to make a navigation menu. A span wraps a group of inline elements or (most usually) plain text. The key word is “group”: if a div wraps just one block-level element, or a span just one inline element, it's being used unnecessarily. For example, check out the way the div and span elements are used in the following simple markup:

[W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span)

```css
.grey_bg {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
 <h1><span class="grey_bg">Hey</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had to target the h1 as well in the css:

```
.grey_bg h1 {
    background: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Comment: the problem doesn't lie in the specificity of your selector, but in the structure of your html.

Comment: In this case the `<span>` is pointless and can be removed. If you really want to, just place the class on the h1 itself: `<h1 class="grey_bg">` and style with `.grey_bg { }`.